# JHipster prod profile build error

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, karma-runner, jhipster

When I try to run `mvn -Pprod spring-boot:run` I get this error:

> Running "karma:unit" (karma) task INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.31 server
>   started at http://localhost:9876/ INFO [launcher]: Starting browser
>   PhantomJS INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X)]: Connected on socket
>   efv9WlKx2MFU9eZQOn6q with id 32802763 DUMP: 'background-image:
>   initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial;
>   background-clip: initial; background-color: rgb(153, 255, 0);
>   background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial
>   initial; ' PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X) Services Tests Auth should call
>   backend on logout then call authServerProvider.logout FAILED Error:
>   Unsatisfied requests: GET /api/account\?cacheBuster=\d+/ at
>   /Users/fontanellif/jhipster-sql/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1559
>   at
>   /Users/fontanellif/jhipster-sql/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1538
>   at
>   /Users/fontanellif/jhipster-sql/src/test/javascript/spec/components/auth/authServicesSpec.js:45
>   Error: Unsatisfied requests: GET /api/account\?cacheBuster=\d+/ at
>   /Users/fontanellif/jhipster-sql/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1559
>   at
>   /Users/fontanellif/jhipster-sql/src/test/javascript/spec/components/auth/authServicesSpec.js:32
>   PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X): Executed 8 of 8 (1 FAILED) (0.009 secs /
>   0.257 secs) Warning: Task "karma:unit" failed. Use --force to continue.

I don't modify the code of the project, just create it with the jhipster generator and then run the command.

Comment: I am looking for the same resolution..

Comment: i meet with the same error